# How to change the default tag in the health check user interface?

Tags: .net-core, masstransit, health-check

I want to change the tags, when I check the health of Rabbitmq, masstransit puts these tags by default.

[health Check UI Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJMhw.png)

I also want to change the name
[HealthCheck Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKWjE.png)

```
  builder.Services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
        {
            configure.AddConsumer<RabbitMqConsumer>();
            configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host($"{messageBroker.Protocol}://{messageBroker.Host}:{messageBroker.Port}", cfgHost =>
                {
                    cfgHost.Username(messageBroker.UserName);
                    cfgHost.Password(messageBroker.Password);
                });
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName: $"{messageBroker.Name}-HealthCheck", config =>
                {
                    config.ConfigureConsumer<RabbitMqConsumer>(context);
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the health check options when configuring MassTransit:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.ConfigureHealthCheckOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Name = "your special name";
        options.Tags.Add("your tag");
    });
});
```